# Determine who can see Administrative Tools?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Since normal users don't have privileges to modify system service settings, e.g. DNS, is it possible to hide the `Administrative Tools` for them but those people in Domain Admins still have privileges to see it?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do it that I know of is to use GPOs to define a Start Menu that doesn't contain the `Administrative Tools` tree for those users you want to "hide" it from.  They'll still be able to get at it through the MMC, but odds are they won't know how or want to be bothered with that.

<kbd>User Configuration</kbd> --> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> --> <kbd>Control Panel Settings</kbd> --> <kbd>Start Menu</kbd>

[image: GPME Start menu]

The other, hackier way would be to mess with the permissions on the item in question.  For Windows Vista and up, it's at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\`, and you could change who has read permissions to the "Administrative Tools" directory tree there.  Presumably via script if you want to do it for a bunch of computers.